# How do I calculate second derivative of involute of circle? I found its first derivative is tantheta but I have no clue how to proceed further

Tags: calculus, parametric

Parametric equations of this involute curve are given as  = (sin  −  cos ) and
 = (cos  +  sin ).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{\frac{dy}{d\theta}}{\frac{dx}{d\theta}}=\tan\theta $$

This is how you proceed further:

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{\frac{dx}{d\theta}}$$